# Can I enable/disable client num-lock using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing c# web application and I want to let user use num-lock as a short key for switch some options on my app but don't want it to disable the num-pad.

Can I achieve this using JavaScript?

EDIT : What I want to do is when user press the key (then the light turn off) but user still can key number to input field

Ex. press 'Num-lock' to buy / press '-' to sell then enter the price

Comment: Please add the steps you have tried towards this so far. and where are you struck.

Comment: Basically, the idea is to prevent the default action when listening the event code appropriate, and doing the right action you want. By this way, you will not trigger the actual "Num lock", and the action you defined will occurs.

Comment: If u want to detect `num lock` is pressed and further action to not to use it... then, you can do that! but you can't disable Num Lock on client side. So, wht's your planning?

Comment: @Vikrant, that's exactly what I want to do, I want to enable Num-Lock on client side,with javascript, this might be impossible but any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the closest to what I'm looking for [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhb5zdv7/8)

```
 $('#textbox').keydown(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    $('#keydownCode').html(keycode);


 if(keycode == 144){
    $('#Typoef').html('It is a Sell');
     //perform Sell operation here
 }
 else if(keycode == 109){
    $('#Typoef').html('It is a Purchase');
     //perform Purchase operation here
 }
 else if(keycode == 35){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"1");
     e.preventDefault();
 }
 else if(keycode == 40){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"2");
     e.preventDefault();
 }
 else if(keycode == 34){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"3");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else if(keycode == 37){
     $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"4");
     e.preventDefault(); 
 }
 else if(keycode == 12){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"5");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else if(keycode == 39){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"6");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else if(keycode == 36){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"7");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else if(keycode == 38){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"8");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }else if(keycode == 33){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"9");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else if(keycode == 45){
    $('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val()+"0");
     e.preventDefault();     
 }
 else{
     $('#Typoef').html('');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this answer performs a check for which `Key` is pressed and accrodingly processes your required operation!

Main part in JS code is :

```
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
$('#keydownCode').html(keycode);
```

And here is the Demo for it!

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhb5zdv7/7/)

**Edit :**

After explanation for "Disabling" `NUM lock`; i.e. reject keystrokes if NUM LOCK is **OFF**, I've created below quick piece of code!

It doesn't accept values when NUM LOCK is OFF!

### [Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhb5zdv7/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts; but what I try to do is, after user press Num-lock, user can still key numbers.

Comment: buddy, i've already told you; that you can't TURN OFF num lock of client using Jscript! If it's possible with JavaScript it rather used for Hacking

Comment: Yes, I know that impossible but maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhb5zdv7/8/ (I hope there's a better way)

Comment: the functions written are Good one, but 'disable' means? do you want to enter number on those clicks, even if Numlock is off? make it clear.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well - it appears that the NumLock key (am quite surprised by this) uses keycode 144 on keydown - so you can pick it up and use it as a "hot key".

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/traceline/q6pb7b30/)

```
$(function(){
    $("input").keydown(function(e){
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

If you want it as a "use it anywhere hot key" you'll want to bind your keydown handler to the body or document rather than a specific element.

Further comment re: disabling the use of numlock (but still wanting to use the num pad).  a) you can't - it's a hardware thing, and b) you've got to question why you would ever want to do that.... if you could, what happens when the user goes away from the browser (and toggles the numlock without you knowing it) - suggest a re-think. (sorry)

Comment: What I want to do is like using e.preventDefault(); to stop the num-pad to be disabled after user press the button. Can I do that?

Comment: no (is the short answer) - it's a hardware-level thing

Comment: that's what I guess. but maybe I can blind a key pressed after num-lock disable and make it behave like numbers?