# preventDefault() action that works on numlock key 144 so that numberpad can still be used for shortcuts

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault, num-lock

I'm trying to build a website that uses the numberpad for keyboard shortcuts to push different buttons. For one of the events I need more than 9 shortcuts. To keep things simple on the user's end I'd like to use the numlock key #144. The problem is that when they use the number lock key it prevents the numbers from working for future button presses. I've tried using the preventDefault(); function but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an alternative that would enable me to do this?

```
if (e.which == 144) { // numlock on the numberpad
  preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("button1").click();
}
if (e.which == 96) { // 0 on the numberpad
  document.getElementById("button2").click();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a strange key to choose. Note that many of the major keys like Alt, Shift Crl/Cmd etc can be used easily in combination with your numbers as they are part of the key event object

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider using that key since it does not exist on some keyboards, like some laptops, Mac keyboards(named Clear instead), mobile devices

Comment: It's added functionality. I'm trying to make a secondary control system that works 100% on the numberpad.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252278/2259571 You might be able to simulate it but you're not really controlling the NUM LOCK behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `preventDefault` off your event parameter, generally `e`. There's no global `preventDefault`.

Also, you can't control the state of the numlock. That is a low level hardware/software implementation.